# Can "packed up" be used instead of "box up" (leftover food)

Tags: word-usage

Can "packed up" be used when asking for taking leftover food home instead of asking for a box?

> Can you pack this up, please?

Does it sound likely?

Or is it always:

> Can I have a box for this please?

> Can I take this home please?

> Can you box this up please?

> Can I have this to-go?

Or in some contexts "wrapped up".

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me. Asking for a doggy bag is also an option (perhaps UK only).

Comment: Yes, doggy bag is used in the US, too. But pack up is okay. Generally, though, pack up would be used like this: He packed up all his junk and left the house.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds idiomatic to me as a British English speaker. We say "a packed lunch" to describe a pre-prepared lunch that we might take to work or school. US English speakers apparently say "boxed lunch". Oddly though, British speakers may call the box we pack our lunch into "a lunchbox".

So yes, I'd understand "can you pack that up". Some regions of the UK even use "packing up" as a noun for their packed lunch.

"To go" is also chiefly American. British people do understand it, and thanks to Hollywood influence some people have started to use it. The more common British expression is to ask for something "to take away" or "take out".

Comment: When used as a noun, I think the term "take out" is actually American. What we call e.g. "a Chinese/Indian take-away" - meaning a place that sells ethnic hot food for consumption away from the premises - Americans will call it a "take-out". Presumably it works the same when each term is used as a verb. But as you correctly point out "...to go" is definitely American.